# how to deal with unverified apt install in ansible

Tags: apt-get, apt, ansible

when installing an apt package from our own repo, I get the the following on the CLI:

```
Install these packages without verification? [y/N]
```

The question is, how does one install these packages successfully using ansible?

Even with the force option, ansible fails to install the package.

The command I'm using is:

```
- apt: name=coupons-graphite dpkg_options='force' state=present
```

Comment: How exactly are you attempting to install these packages?  Are you using the apt module or are you invoking apt-get or something similar yourself? An example of a task where you're seeing this would be helpful.

Comment: @BruceP thank you. I've edited the post to reflect the command I'm using.

Comment: Rather than use `dpkg_options='force'` what happens if you use `force=yes`? The [documentation for the apt module](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_module.html) states that `force=yes` should force the install.

Comment: the proper command is: `- apt: name=coupons-graphite force=yes state=present` I missed it somehow.

Comment: @BruceP or Seth, you should put that as a proper answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation for the apt module](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_module.html) you should be using `force=yes` in this case:

```
- apt: name=coupons-graphite
       state=present
       force=yes
```